# Thickness map grid type

Tags: displacement

I'm wondering how I could had a thickness to this pattern made with a map (1) ?
 [image]
I don't want to model it because the idea, is to change very often new sort of pattern to have a quick review of what it looks like in an object, there is a lots of pattern, the proportion are constently changing, so an other team do it in illustrator.

I tried solidify modifier but part are missing (2)
[image]
I tried the displacement map (nodal), but it is not strong enough

I tried the displacement modifier but it is way too much heavy and the result is not sharpe at all

and now I'm running out of solution, any Idea o help ?

Comment: Yeah you can't really just add thickness to an image texture just like that, if you could no one would really ever bother modelling, they'd just make textures. If it was done in illustrator try importing it as an SVG curve and then extrude it.

Comment: Also you could take the image to the compositor first and add some Dilate/Erode node to it, then save and use.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret the question. Do you want to make each "Y" shape looking 3D or do you want white parts to be higher than black ones? Also, could you provide a blend file with the overall shape and the map?